# Java Socket Chat unable to establish connection to port

Tags: java, sockets, ports

I am trying to code a simple server and client chat application, however my code jumps straight to the exception, meaning it cannot create the connection to the port.

Server:

```
public class Server
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
   try
   {
       ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(80);
       Socket sock = ss.accept();
       DataInputStream recive = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
       DataOutputStream sendOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
       BufferedReader readOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

       String in = "";
       String out = "";
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Talk with client(y/n): ");
       String start = scan.nextLine();
       while(start == "y")
       {
       in = recive.readUTF();
       System.out.println(in);
       out = readOut.readLine();
       sendOut.writeUTF(out);
       sendOut.flush();
      }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {System.out.println("[!]CANNOT ESTABLISH CONNECTION[!]");}

  }
}
```

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` would really help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the port that you have specified is not already in use (port number 80) . It is likely that you may be running another application on the same port (such as a web server).

Comment: I have used serveral different ports, like 1234,9090, and 80. None seem to work. On both my home computer and computer at school

Comment: Can you give the complete stack trace?

Comment: When I run it in Jelliot or set a breakpoint it does not make it past line 19 or  ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(whatever port i provide);

Comment: Has Java been allowed in the firewall to listen to incoming connections?